# Is stream processing atomic / transactional when using at least once delivery in Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let's suppose a simple case like this:

```
ORDER_TOPIC ----> KSTREAM ----> VALIDATED_ORDER_TOPIC
                     |
          ROCKSDB LOCAL STATE STORE
```

The KStream deduplicates the messages from ORDER_TOPIC using a transform operation with a transformer that stores the messages in a persistent local state store by their key/id. This way if the same order arrives twice it will be ignored.

Now a new order arrives, it's not duplicated so it's stored in the local store but before sending it to the VALIDATED_ORDER_TOPIC the application crashes.

I'm wondering what the transactional guarantees are inside a KStream: has the record been stored and committed to the local state store or rolledback?

Could you point at some documentation regarding transactional guarantees for Kafka Streams with at-least-once semantics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run with at-least-once semantics, there are no transactional guarantees. For this case, if you first add the ID to the store, but you crash before the record is written to the output topic, you may loose this record when it is reprocessed from the input topic.

If you want to de-duplicate, you need to enable `processing.guarantees=exactly_once`. For this case, if you crash, the store will be "rolled back" into a consistent state. Ie, after a crash, it will contain the ID only if the write to the output topic was successful.